# MySQL join based on newest row in right table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, limit

I am trying to join two tables in MySQL and only show one row which should be the newest row in the right table based on a date field.

Users

```
id    name
1     John
2     James
3     Peter
```

Orders

```
id    user_id   value   order_date
1     1         35      2016-06-01
2     1         25      2016-06-05
3     1         10      2016-06-07
4     2         20      2016-06-02
5     3         18      2016-06-07
```

Expected output

```
John 10 2016-06-07
James 20 2016-06-02
Peter 18 2016-06-07
```

Query

```
select 
    name, value, order_date 
from 
    users 
left join 
    orders on users.id = orders.user_id
```

Received output

```
John 35 2016-06-01
John 25 2016-06-05
John 10 2016-06-07
James 20 2016-06-02
Peter 18 2016-06-07
```

I cannot add limit 1 or order to the overall query as this will only return one row overall which is not correct so some how it needs to be added into the join but I cannot figure out how to? I am assuming some sort of subquery but do I do the subquery in the select or the join or both?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have only 1 record per user_id per date

you can just use `MAX()` this way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/658ce/5

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    o.value, 
    o.order_date 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT 
      user_id,
      MAX(order_date) max_date
   FROM orders 
   GROUP BY user_id
  ) orders
ON users.id = orders.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    orders o 
ON o.user_id = orders.user_id
  AND orders.max_date = o.order_date
```

Comment: Good point - there could be more than one order per user per day hence why I thought using order on date and then maybe id for example might be needed so it is always the most recent entry. There isn't any other way in the dataset to tell which is the most recent as it is a date and not datetime field which is used

Comment: if you have no column with date-time you will never be sure what record is *most recent* that is just guessing. sometimes `id` is not something solid you can trust.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
select name, value, order_date 
from users 
left join orders o on users.id = o.user_id
where not exists (
    select 1
    from orders o2
    where o2.user_id = o.user_id
      and o2.id > o.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in (subquery for the max(order_date, user_id))

```
SELECT 
u.name
, o.value
, o.order_date 
from user as u 
inner join orders o on u.user_id = o.user_id
and (o.user_id, o.order_date in (user_id, max(order_date) 
                                   from orders group by user_id)
```